# White screen of death for wp-admin and error for wp-login.php after entering credentials

Tags: wp-admin, wp-login-form, fatal-error

I am getting the white screen for wp-admin and "ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress" when i try to login through wp-login.php

Earlier i was getting the same error but i looked  for the white space after `<?php` and before `?>`. And the problem was solved. But then i realized that all the jscripts stopped loading and none of the sliders were working.

I even tried to run the same site on my local host and found the same problem. After a long time i found out problem with the database. I switched back to earlier version of database. And everything is working fine on my localhost.
But then on the live server i uploaded the new database.And now jscripts are loading fine. But getting the same white screen of death and  "ERROR: Cookies are blocked......".
My functions.php is same i.e without any white spaces'   . 
What is it that i am doing wrong.please help.Following is my functions.php

```
<?php
/*************************
Define Constants
**************************/
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

define('THEMEROOT',get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
define('IMAGES',THEMEROOT. '/images');
define('JS', THEMEROOT. '/js');   


if ( ! isset( $content_width ) )
              $content_width = 900;

function xtreme_enqueue_comments_reply() {
    if( get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )  {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'comment_form_before', 'xtreme_enqueue_comments_reply' );

remove_all_filters( 'wp_title' );
wp_title();

function register_my_menu(){
    register_nav_menus(array(
    'topmenu'=>__('Top Menu','basswaves-framework'),
    ));
}
add_action('widgets_init','register_my_menu');

// function skematik_jquery_js(){
//     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
// }

function wpEnqueueScripts(){
    //wp_register_script( "jquery", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.js', array(), false, true );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-min', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery-ui-min.js', array('jquery'),false , true );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'Bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'),false , true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/isotope.pkgd.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/main2.js', array('jquery'), false, true );    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/owl.carousel.js', array('jquery'),false , true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/script.js', array('jquery'),false , true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'fancy', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.fancybox.js', array('jquery'),false , true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'sliphover', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.sliphover.min.js', array('jquery'),false , true );   

}
/* Load Scripts */
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpEnqueueScripts');

function wpt_register_css() {
    wp_register_style('bootstrap.min',get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );

     wp_enqueue_style(
            'jquery-ui-calendar',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery-ui.min.css',
            false,
            'all'
        );

      wp_enqueue_style(
            'calendar',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/datepicker.css',
            false,
            'all'
        );

       wp_enqueue_style(
            'owlcss1',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.theme.css',
            false,
            'all'
        );

        wp_enqueue_style(
            'SpryTabbcss',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/owl.carousel.css',
            false,
            'all'
        );
          wp_enqueue_style(
            'fancy',
            get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery.fancybox.css',
            false,
            'all'
        );



}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_register_css' );

require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'sliderimg', 200, 150, true );
}


add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );


if(function_exists('register_sidebar')){

    register_sidebar(
        array(

            'name'=>__('About Sidebar','basswaves-framework'),
            'id'=>'about',
            'description'=> __('The Main sidebar area ','basswaves-framework'),
            'before_widget'=> '',
            'after_widget'=>'',
            'before_title'=>'<h5>',
            'after_title'=>'<span> Basswaves.</span></h5>'
            ));     
    register_sidebar(
        array(

            'name'=>__('Our Service','basswaves-framework'),
            'id'=>'services',
            'description'=> __('The Main sidebar area ','basswaves-framework'),
            'before_widget'=> '',
            'after_widget'=>'',
            'before_title'=>'<h5>',
            'after_title'=>'<span> Basswaves.</span></h5>'
            ));


}

/*to limit the length of the_excerpt*/


add_action( 'init', 'cyb_event_gallery_rewrite_rule' );
 function cyb_event_gallery_rewrite_rule() {
     add_rewrite_rule( '^events/([^/]+)/gallery/?$', 'index.php?events=$matches[1]&gallery=yes', 'top' );
 }

 add_filter( 'query_vars', 'cyb_register_gallery_query_var' );
 function cyb_register_gallery_query_var( $vars ) {
     $vars[] = 'gallery';
     return $vars;
 }

 add_filter( 'template_include', function($template) {
     if ( get_query_var( 'gallery' ) ) {
         return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-events-gallery.php';
     }
     return $template;
 });



 /*Add meta boxes to only specific post*/
 add_action('admin_init','my_meta_init');

function my_meta_init(){
    $post_id = $_GET['post'] ? $_GET['post'] : $_POST['post_ID'] ;

    // checks for post/page ID

        add_meta_box('team_meta', __('Our Team','uep'), 'team_meta_1', 'post', 'normal', 'high');






    function team_meta_1(){
    global $post;
    // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="eventmeta_noncename" id="eventmeta_noncename" value="' . 
    wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

    // Get the location data if its already been entered
    $designation = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_designation', true);
    $contact=get_post_meta($post->ID, '_contact', true);
    $email=get_post_meta($post->ID, '_email', true);
    $facebook=get_post_meta($post->ID, '_facebook', true);
    $twitter=get_post_meta($post->ID, '_twitter', true);
    $gmail=get_post_meta($post->ID, '_gmail', true);
    $linkedin=get_post_meta($post->ID, '_linkedin', true);


    // Echo out the field
    // echo '<input type="text" name="_description" value="' . $description  . '" />';
    echo '<label class="teamlabel"  for="_designation">Designation</label>
    <textarea name="_designation" rows="2" cols="30">'.$designation.'</textarea><br>';
    echo '<label class="teamlabel" for="_contact">Contact</label>
    <textarea name="_contact" rows="2" cols="30">'.$contact.'</textarea><br>';
    echo '<label class="teamlabel" for="_email">Email</label>
    <textarea name="_email" rows="2" cols="30">'.$email.'</textarea><br>';
    echo '<label class="teamlabel" for="_facebook">Facebook</label>
    <textarea name="_facebook" rows="2" cols="30">'.$facebook.'</textarea><br>';
    echo '<label class="teamlabel"  for="_twitter">Twitter</label>
    <textarea name="_twitter" rows="2" cols="30">'.$twitter.'</textarea><br>';
    echo '<label class="teamlabel"  for="_gmail">Gmail:</label>
    <textarea name="_gmail" rows="2" cols="30">'.$gmail.'</textarea><br>';
    echo '<label class="teamlabel" for="_linkedin">Linkedin</label>
    <textarea name="_linkedin" rows="2" cols="30">'.$linkedin.'</textarea><br>';
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            (function ($) {
                $('#in-category-18').change(function () { $('#team_meta').toggle(this.checked); }).change();
            })(jQuery);
        });
    </script>
    <?php 
  }   


    function my_meta_save($post_id, $post) {

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['eventmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
    return $post->ID;
    }

    // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
        return $post->ID;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data
    // We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.

    $events_meta['_designation'] = $_POST['_designation'];
    $events_meta['_contact'] = $_POST['_contact'];
    $events_meta['_email'] = $_POST['_email'];
    $events_meta['_facebook'] = $_POST['_facebook'];
    $events_meta['_twitter'] = $_POST['_twitter'];
    $events_meta['_gmail'] = $_POST['_gmail'];
    $events_meta['_linkedin'] = $_POST['_linkedin'];



    // Add values of $events_meta as custom fields

    foreach ($events_meta as $key => $value) { // Cycle through the $events_meta array!
        if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return; // Don't store custom data twice
        $value = implode(',', (array)$value); // If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely)
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value
            update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value
            add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
        }
        if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key); // Delete if blank
    }

}

 add_action('save_post','my_meta_save',10,2);

}


/*To limit the no of words for the_exceprt() */


function string_limit_words($string, $word_limit)
{
  $words = explode(' ', $string, ($word_limit + 1));
  if(count($words) > $word_limit)
  array_pop($words);
  return implode(' ', $words);
}

function wp_get_attachment( $attachment_id ) {

    $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );
    return array(
        'alt' => get_post_meta( $attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true ),
        'caption' => $attachment->post_excerpt,
        'description' => $attachment->post_content,
        'href' => get_permalink( $attachment->ID ),
        'src' => $attachment->guid,
        'title' => $attachment->post_title
    );
}

function  strip_shortcode_gallery( $content ) {
    preg_match_all( '/'. get_shortcode_regex() .'/s', $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );
    if ( ! empty( $matches ) ) {
        foreach ( $matches as $shortcode ) {
            if ( 'gallery' === $shortcode[2] ) {
                $pos = strpos( $content, $shortcode[0] );
                if ($pos !== false)
                    return substr_replace( $content, '', $pos, strlen($shortcode[0]) );
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

/*******************************************************
Function to display comments
********************************************************/
function basswaves_comments($comment, $args, $depth){
    $GLOBALS['comment']=$comment;

    if(get_comment_type()=='pingback'||get_comment_type()=='trackback'): ?>

     <div class="pingback" id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">  
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <?php 
               $avatar_size=80;
               if($comment->comment_parent !=0){
                  $avatar_size=64;
               }
               echo get_avatar($comment,$avatar_size);
            ?>
        </div>                   
        <div  <?php echo comment_class('col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10'); ?> >
            <h4><?php _e('Pingback','basswaves-framework'); ?><span> <?php edit_comment_link(); ?></span></h4>
            <?php if($comment->comment_approved=='0'): ?>
            <p><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation ','basswaves-framework'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php comment_author_link(); ?>
        </div>
     </div>
                 <hr>
<?php elseif(get_comment_type()=='comment'): ?>

     <div class="row comment-desc" id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">  
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
            <?php 
               $avatar_size=80;
               if($comment->comment_parent !=0){
                  $avatar_size=64;
               }
               echo get_avatar($comment,$avatar_size);
            ?>
        </div>                   
        <div  <?php echo comment_class('col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10'); ?> >
            <h4><?php comment_author_link(); ?><span> on <?php comment_date() ?> at <?php comment_time(); ?></span></h4>
            <?php if($comment->comment_approved=='0'): ?>
            <p><?php _e('Your comment is awaiting moderation ','basswaves-framework'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php comment_text(); ?>
            <?php comment_reply_link(array_merge($args,array(depth=>$depth,'max-depth'=>$args['max-depth']))); ?>
        </div>
     </div>
                 <hr>
<?php 
endif; 
 }

 /************************************************************************
 Custom Comments Form
 ************************************************************************/
 function basswave_custom_comment_form($defaults){
    $defaults['comment_notes_before']='';
    $defaults['class_form']='row leavecomment';
    $defaults['comment_notes_after']='';
    $defaults['comment_field']='<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                                <textarea rows="3" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                </div>';


    return $defaults;
 }
 add_filter('comment_form_defaults','basswave_custom_comment_form');
 function basswave_custom_comment_fields(){
    $commenter= wp_get_current_commenter();
    $req=get_option('require_name_email');
    $aria_req=($req ? " aria-required='true'":'');
    $fields=array(
                   'author'=>  '<div class="row">'.
                               '<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">'.
                               '<input type="text" class="form-control"  value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author']).'" '.$aria_req.' />'.
                               '</div>'.
                               '<label for ="author">'.__('Name','basswaves-framework').''.($req?'*':'').'</label>'.                               
                               '</div>',  
                    'email'=>  '<div class="row">'.
                               '<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">'.
                               '<input type="text" class="form-control"  value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_email']).'" '.$aria_req.' />'.
                               '</div>'.
                               '<label for ="email">'.__('Email','basswaves-framework').''.($req?'*':'').'</label>'.                               
                               '</div>',   

                    'url'=>  '<div class="row">'.
                               '<div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5">'.
                               '<input type="text" class="form-control"  value="'.esc_attr($commenter['comment_author_url']).'" '.$aria_req.' />'.
                               '</div>'.
                               '<label for ="url">'.__('Website','basswaves-framework').'</label>'.                               
                               '</div>',  

                  );
    return $fields;
 }   

 add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','basswave_custom_comment_fields');
?>
```

Comment: There is too much going on in that `functions.php` without certainty it has anything to do with the issue. What happens if you switch to default theme? If you disable plugins?

Comment: after i disable the plugins nothing happens but when i switch to default theme(i.e i renamed my theme).I am able to access wp-admin but not the wp-login.php(white screen). And now i not able to logout of the admin panel, gets the white screen

Comment: @user3848698 have you [Turned on Debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG)? Probably turn that on and `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG');` and sort out your errors from there.

Comment: @ Howdy_McGee                                                     i wrote                                              define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );                                       but i am not seeing any debug.log in wp-content/

Comment: I am getting no errors although i created debug.log in wp-content

Comment: I just found out that the problem was due to a plugin i wrote for the custom post type. So can any body guide me that how do i troubleshoot my problem within it